# Writing a wrapper class for an ActiveX control

Tags: c++, activex, wrapper, word-wrap, firebreath

I am given a video calling software which implements an activex control to render the video in a web browser. As activex works only in IE i am given the task of implementing a cross-browser version of the activex control using FireBreath framework.
I need to write a wrapper class for the activeX control.

I am new to activex,visual studio(eveything involved in the project). And the activex  code has thousands of lines of code. It is taking a long time for me to understand the code.

Does anyone have any good example wrapper classes and any other suggestions or links which would help my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I know of is this: https://github.com/firebreath/FBAXExample

It's an example of hosting an activex control inside a FireBreath plugin. You'd be better off (and a lot cleaner) if you can do a complete port, but it may be possible to do it with just a wrapper; you may also want to look at the WebView library in FireBreath itself, which embeds IE inside a FireBreath plugin.  You can find it here: https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/tree/master/src/libs/WebView/Win